# Подсветка констант из других библиотек работает неправильно. Как это исправить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Сборка и выполнение программы проходят как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double f1(double x){
    return sin(x) * sin(2 * x) * sin(3 * x);
}
double f2(double x){
    return 1 / (5 - 3 * cos(x));
}
double rect (double a, double b, int n, double (*f)(double)){
    double  h = (b - a) / n, 
            s, 
            x = a - h;
            
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        x += h;
        s += f(x);
    }
    
    return s * h;
}

int main(){
    cout << "First integral = " << rect(0, M_PI / 2, 100, f1);
    cout << "\nSecond integral = " << rect(0, 3 / 2 * M_PI, 200, f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно настраивать [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)

Comment: @spatz, спасибо

Comment: `M_PI` не входит в стандартный С++, видимо поэтому.